# How to Change Inner text of xml file which having duplicate node using Xpath

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
   <buttons>   
      <workshop1>hello</workshop1>  
       <workshop1>Google</workshop1>    
      <url1>www.google.co.uk</url1> 
    </buttons>
    </Reports>
```

Above is my xml file .how should i change inner text of Duplicate Node.for Exampla in Above xml i have to change Second node Google to  yahoo using XPath in c#.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare proper prefix to namespace URI mapping, then you can use XPath query using that prefix plus specifying element index to select the second `<workshop1>` element, for example :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager oManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
oManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
var google = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Report/ns:buttons/ns:workshop1[2]", oManager).InnerText;
```